# RxJava and Kotlin's platform types: sanity check

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

This is mostly a sanity check on my thinking.

I'm observing an RxJava2 stream from a Kotlin class. Kotlin is converting these to Observables/Singles/Flowables of platform types (e.g. `Observable<Widget!>`). I see there is very little talk of that [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rxjava+kotlin+%22platform+type)

So since RxJava2 cannot emit null, can I safely assume any emitted type is a non-nullable Kotlin type? In other words, can I rely on RxJava to throw a NullPointerException before the object ever makes it to the subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe (too bad RxJava doesn't use annotations to make Kotlin understand this automatically). But you could use [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) which restricts type parameters to be non-nullable where this makes sense.